# Updating hibernate associations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am creating RESTful Web Service. Client is allowed to register `Company` and then update it if needed. `Company` has `Address` association. When user request `Company` update it sends `Company` object id and `Company` involving `Address` object without `Address`es id. To update `Company` object I use hibernate `merge` method. It sets correctly new `Company` data but it creates new `Address` row instead of updating it.

How can I solve this problem?

I could fetch `Address` by `company.getAddress()` get it's id and merge new `Address` but when I do that all `Company` data is being fetched, which I think is not good.

```
    public class Company implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I could also write a custom query

```
UPDATE address SET city='NEW YORK' FROM companies WHERE address.id = companies.address_id
```

but I want it to be a default action. If you see any association without id use the above query.

Comment: When you merge a company, all the company data is being fetched as well. Don't pre-optimize. Make it work, and if you have a performance problem, than see where it comes from and optimize this part. Fetching a company and its address by ID is extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you are using the merge instead of directly updating the Address object that was requested.

eg. (pseudocode)

```
Company c = (Company)query.findbyid(id)
Address a = c.getAddress()

a.setField1(field1);
a.setField2(field2);
a.setField3(field3);

pm.commit(c);
```

Two thing you need to check if you are set on using the merge technique:
1. The address association is lazy loaded which means that it is null until you request for it. Could it be that you detached the Company object from the PersistenceManager and then try to merge?

1. Also, I am assuming that your Address is also an entity. It would have generated id (primarykey). Make sure that you don't mess that up. If it regenerates a new id, you are going to get another row.